# Remove 'disable' property from select box when another box is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I have two select boxes where user can choose category and subcategory. I want to subcategory be disabled by default and enabled when user has previously selected the category.

```
<select name="cat" onclick="this.form.submit()" style="width:220px;height:120px;" size="8">
    <option value="">All categories</option>
        @foreach($categoriesFilter as $cf)
            <option value="{{ $cf->mainCat_de }}">{{ $cf->mainCat_de }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="subcat" id="subcat" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="width:220px;height:120px;" size="8" disabled>
    <option value="">All subcategories</option>
        @foreach($subCategoriesFilter as $sf)
            <option value="{{ $sf->cat_de }}">{{ $sf->cat_de }}</option>
        @endforeach
</select>
```

I tried to do this, but it's not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cat = {{ Request::get('cat') }};

    if( cat != "" || cat != null ){
        $('#subcat').prop('disabled', false);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Is `cat` a string?

Comment: Try `$('#subcat').removeProp('disabled');` instead. What you're doing is assigning the property a value of `false`. I've found jQuery some times doesn't see disabled as a property. So try `$(...).attr('disabled',null)` as well.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes. It is a string (variable from URL).

Comment: You need to wrap the value in quotes then: `var cat = '{{ Request::get('cat') }}';`

Comment: Yep. It's working now. Thx a lot @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to use Variable from Laravel's Blade that is a string, it must be wrapped in quotes.

What your code could equate to is `var cat = fruits`, which will throw a syntax error. By wrapping the blade in quotes, you're correctly saying `var cat = "fruits"`.

```
var cat = "{{ Request::get('cat') }}";

$('#subcat').prop('disabled', cat == "" || cat == null);
```

Comment: But it is `onclick="this.form.submit()"` .. When I choose something from cat, it submits the form and reloads the page.

Comment: Okay, just realised. One second updating answer